# C# reportviewer is showing no data

Tags: c#

```
private void SetReportSource()
{
    DataTable dt;

    dt = FrmSummaryController.GetSummaryReport();

    this.rptMySummary.Reset();
    this.rptMySummary.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsNewDataSet_Table", dt);

    //this.rptMySummary.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    this.rptMySummary.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

    this.rptMySummary.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

This is my code to populate report viewer. I am sure that there are 6 lines of data in coming in data table dt.

Still there are no lines and no headings in report viewer.

Can you please advise what am I doing wrong.

Comment: If it's docked inside something else maybe that too needs to be refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps. and Report binding is missing

```
reportDocument.Load(this.MapPath("crpt_test.rpt"));<br>
reportDocument.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(dsReport.Tables[0]);<br>
rptviewer.ReportSource = IT_proj_reportDocument;<br>
rptviewer.Visible = true;<br>
rptviewer.DataBind();<br>
```

Export to any file format.